Conditional filter javascript (react) - combining two logical operators - || and && or && and &&
Basically in my react app I want to filter an array that meets 3 conditions, but if I use && (and) two times it doesn't work, only if I use  || (or) and  && (and) together.
Example of data:
// url /practice/${tName}/${level}/play/${nextPage}
// this case url - /practice/Animals/1/play/1
 const { name: tName, pageNumber, box, level } = useParams();

    const userInfo = [{
        _id: '660dc1cbb2ac9d1ad31b59b2'
        },{
        _id: '660dc1cbb2ac9d1ad31b59b3'
        }]

    const initialTasks = [{
    class: 'Animals',
    level: 1,
    rank: 1,
    nr: 1,
    part1: 'animals task 1 level 1 user 1',
    user: '660dc1cbb2ac9d1ad31b59b2'
},
{
    class: 'Animals',
    level: 1,
    rank: 1,
    nr: 2,
    part1: 'animals task 2 level 1 user 1',
    user: '660dc1cbb2ac9d1ad31b59b2'
},
{
    class: 'Animals',
    level: 2,
    rank: 1,
    nr: 3,
    part1: 'animals task 3 level 2 user 1',
    user: '660dc1cbb2ac9d1ad31b59b2'
},
{
    class: 'Animals',
    level: 1,
    rank: 1,
    nr: 1,
    part1: 'animals task 1 level 1 user 2',
    user: '660dc1cbb2ac9d1ad31b59b3'
},
{
    class: 'Hotel',
    level: 1,
    rank: 1,
    nr: 1,
    part1: 'hotel task 1 level 1 user 1',
    user: '660dc1cbb2ac9d1ad31b59b2'
},

Why this code doesn't work? const tasksFiltered = initalTasks.filter(t => t.class === tName && t.level === level && t.user === userInfo._id);
But this one works? const tasksFiltered = initialTasks.filter(t => t.class === tName || t.level === level && t.user === userInfo._id);
I thought || (or) means that just one condition has to be true and the other one can be false...
My objective is when each user is on this page, the filter returns only the tasks that corrrespond to the url params.
PS: This is a simplified example, this data is being fetched trough redux from the database.

Using either makes sense in separate use cases... what kind of filtering are you wanting to do? When all conditions are met, or only when some of them are? Also, FWIW the second example is ambiguous without grouping, e.g. do you mean "(cond1 || cond2) && cond3" or do you mean "cond1 || (cond2 && cond3)"? See the difference?

Please give an example of your data.

Why is this essentially the same question as this one from a different user account?

@Drew Reese, all conditions must be true, i don't understand why we've to user 'or'. It's 1 and 2 and 3 that must be true. Not 1 or 2 and 3, neither (1 or 2) and 3 that must be true. I still don't see the difference.

@ryanwebjackson, I don't see where is the relevance in giving you the example of data, but there you are. Now can you explain me why this happen?

@Phil, yes is essentially the same question from that different user, but until now no expert could give a good answer.

The difference would be exactly as you explained needing all 3 conditions to evaluate truthy, i.e. cond1 && cond2 && cond3, sans any groupings. If your question is really why doing this doesn't work then it might be because of your data.... or maybe there's a misunderstanding of the UI/UX that makes an assumption that all 3 conditions must be met.

@Drew Reese it can be really a misunderstanding, because in reality this code is being fetch from the database, using redux and mongoDB.

I think I see what the issue is now, including the data helped. I have voted to reopen. In the meantime can you [edit] to clarify what exactly is working in one versus what isn't working in the other, and clarify what you expect the result to be from the first example that isn't working?

Having the data helps us understand why the code is "failing". We can create a reproducible example then. Else, we are guessing as to what the true problem is.

userInfo is an array of objects that have a _id property, the code in both cases incorrectly accesses a _id property of the array instead of the array elements.

Why this code doesn't work? const tasksFiltered = initalTasks.filter(t => t.class === tName && t.level === level && t.user === userInfo._id);
But this one works? const tasksFiltered = initialTasks.filter(t => t.class === tName || t.level === level && t.user === userInfo._id);

With the first example all operands need to evaluate truthy in order to be included in the result array while in the second only one operand needs to return truthy because of the logical OR (||) operator.
What I suspect is happening in the second code example is that the t.class === tName sometimes returns true and because of the OR operator it doesn't matter the other "half" of the condition, the first half already is truthy. This does return results, but likely isn't the results you are expecting.
I suspect you want the first code example where all three conditions must be true, and if so, then the third condition always fails because userInfo._id is undefined, e.g. an undefined array property. Update the logic to search the userInfo array for an element that has a matching _id property.
Example:
const tasksFiltered = initialTasks.filter(task =>
  task.class === tName &&
  task.level === level &&
  userInfo.some(user => user._id === task.user);
);

This way the task class, level, and user properties all need to be conditionally matched.
